# How can I Launch the Device Emulator in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7-emulator

I cannot find the Device Emulator in tools in my visual Studio 2010, how can I launch it? I am currently developing an asp.net website.

Comment: Please give details about your developing environment.

Comment: @uDaY asp.net and csharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How to: Start an Application in Windows Phone Emulator** 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402565(v=vs.92).aspx

> To start an application in Windows Phone Emulator
>
> In Visual Studio, open a Windows Phone project.
>
> If you are using Windows Phone SDK 7.1, on the Standard toolbar, click
> Windows Phone Emulator.
>
> [image]
>
> -or-
>
> If you are using Windows Phone SDK 7.1.1 Update CTP, on the Standard
> toolbar, click Windows Phone Emulator - 512 MB or Windows Phone
> Emulator – 256 MB.
>
> [image] 
> [image]
>
> On the Debug menu, click Start Debugging, or press F5.
>
> Your application is deployed to the emulator and starts.

Comment: Thanks although I was hoping I can do it straight from my asp.net website project...

Answer (score 1):

C:\Program Files\Microsoft XDE\1.0 and run XDE.exe, some params are necessary to start.
Windows phone sdk is required.